# How to break broad webpage into several pages for printing?

Tags: html, css, page-break

Long vertical webpages are usually automatically broken into several pages when you print them. [You can also indicate page breaks using CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-break-inside).

But when you try to print a *broad* webpage, e.g. a timeline that scrolls horizontally, the whole page gets scaled to fit onto a single sheet of paper, making it extremely small and impossible to read.

How can I indicate in the code of the page that I want the page to be printed on several pages, as shown on the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This an interesting question.
The first thing that come up to my mind is to make a sort of "responsive print" by specifying a print style sheet (i.e.: `<style media="print">`) and use it to format the page as a vertical arrangement of the broad page to have it printed as you want.